# PHP 5.6.* vs 7.0.* syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)

Tags: php-7

Strange my research has not turned'up this exact scenario:

`$someVar = $this->StaticClassName::$staticClassProperty;`

php 7.* happily accesses the property but 5.6.* (.11 in this case) falls over with the error:

*unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)*

And yes, I've tried every ${permutation}:: I could think of.

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution? I'm dealing with this as well. Here is some code to exemplify: `<?php 

class MyClass {
 
 public static $var = 'yay!';
 public $childClass;
 
 public function __construct() {
  
  $this->childClass = new ChildClass();
  
 }
 
}

class ChildClass {
 
 public static $var = 'yay?';
 
}

$obj = new MyClass();

echo $obj::$var; // works
echo $obj->childClass::$var; // syntax error

?>`

Answer (score 8):

There's a lot of compound expressions like this which don't work in PHP 5. Usually the solution is to break it into multiple expressions, and you can do that here:

```
$className = $this->StaticClassName;
$someVar = $className::$staticClassProperty;
```

This works on both PHP 5 and PHP 7.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here at least is one solution that may be passable for your needs:

```
<?php 

class MyClass {

    public $childClass;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->childClass = new ChildClass();

    }

}

class ChildClass {

    public static $foo = 'bar';

    public function getFoo() {

        return static::$foo;

    }

}

$obj = new MyClass();

echo $obj->childClass->getFoo();

?>
```